# Most compact way to check if a javascript variable is a string and then trim it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I could do:

```
let value = array[index];
if (typeof value === 'string') {
    value = value.trim();
}
```

Just curious if there is a there is a more compact way to do this?

Comment: Well can't you omit the `instanceof` check? Is it your intention to update the original array element too?

Comment: Are you running into performance issues? If not I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: `typeof value.trim == 'function' && value.trim()`…? If it quacks like a duck…

Comment: `typeof` is enough, no need for `instanceof`

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to had a lot of votes, but also had comments explaining why you don't need `instanceof`.

Comment: I could code a simple utility that performs the string check, but I wanted to see whether there's anything new in javascript that facilitates this use case ... as it seems to be something that's pretty universal ...

Comment: Arguably the fact that a certain value is of a certain type still doesn't guarantee that you can call a specific method on it, with everything being as malleable as it is… checking whether the value has a method `trim` is really the only way to be sure.

Comment: Why do you have a value that you do not know the type of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `||`. You can just do `typeof value === 'string'`; that should suffice.

If you wanna do it the slightly more unreadable way but slightly more compact way, you could do:

```
let value = array[index]

value = typeof value === 'string' && value.trim() || value
```

Or a ternary:

```
let value = array[index]

value = typeof value === 'string' ? value.trim() : value
```

The way you have it is probably fine, though. A good rule of thumb is to prefer more readable but verbose code (versus less readable but more compact).

@nnnnnn has pointed out an even more compact way:

`typeof value === 'string' && (value = value.trim())`

Comment: `if (typeof value === 'string') value = value.trim()` is more compact than either option that you show.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah you could do that. I'm not a fan of removing braces `{}` though in general for `if` statements (only really a problem on the front end I guess, if you're using an uglifier since it might interpret the code incorrectly)

Comment: `if (typeof value === 'string') { value = value.trim() }` is *still* more compact...

Comment: `typeof value === 'string' && (value = value.trim())` is fairly compact, but the same as the `if` without `{}` (without changing `===` to `==` and removing spaces, etc.).

Comment: @JoshBeam In what scenario would an uglifier be confused by missing curly brackets?

Comment: The `||` version is incorrect, it does not work with whitespace-only strings. You definitely should use the more readable *and* more compact *and* more correct solution with the ternary.